# Python - Is there a way to have two separate print functions on one line

Tags: python

I was wondering if it was possible to have two print() functions on the same line. I know that this is impractical but I just wanted to use print as an example. So something like:

> ```
> print('words') print('some more words')
> ```

Rather than:

> ```
> print('words')
> print('some more words')
> ```

or:

> ```
> print('words', 'some more words')
> ```

I got curious after seeing `print([character.isdigit() for char in value])` as an equivalent to:

> ```
> for character in value:
>     print(character.isdigit())
> ```

Being able to put it all in one line interested me. Let me know if it is practical in any situation at all.

Comment: You could put a semicolon between the two statements.  Note that the printed output will still appear on two separate lines (unless you add a `end=''` parameter).

Comment: That `print` statement with a list is *not* equivalent to a loop with a single `print` in its body.

Comment: `print([character.isdigit() for char in value])` is **absolutely not equivalent** to the for-loop you showed.

Comment: Anway, `print` is just a function. Any two simple statements, like an expression statement, can be seperated by a semicolon. so `print(x); print(y)`. But *dont' do that*

Comment: Also note, the list comprehensions really aren't about "putting everything onto one line". The number of lines is really not the major issue of concern, rather, list comprehensions provide a declarative, expressive language construct to create mapping/filtering operations on iterables to create lists.

Comment: Note, you *could* just put your for-loop on one line: `for character in value: print(character.isdigit())`, but again, that is not the same as `print([character.isdigit() for character in value])`

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you want something like:

```
print('words', 'more words', sep="\n", end="\n")
```

We use the `sep` parameter to tell `print` what separator to use between items, and `end` to ensure a newline is printed at the end.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to print 2 custom strings, you may be interesting in formatting your string:

```py
string1 = 'words'
string2 = 'some more words'

print(f'{string1}, {string2}')
```

Outputs

```
words, some more words
```

---

As a practical solution, it depends on how and why your're using it. Formatting strings is very common for reporting variables back to the user, but you wouldn't use it if was more sensible to use two `print` statements. Like:

```py
print(variable1)
print(variable2)
```

Is preferred over

```py
print(f'{variable1}\n{variable2}')
```